# Qt - How to get selected custom items from a QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I created the class `OptionList` derived from `QListWidget` and the class `ListItem` derived from `QListWidgetItem`

in the class `OptionList` I tried using `QList<ListItem *> items = selectedItems();` to get the selected items from the list, but it shows the following error:

`conversion from QList<QListWidgetItem *> to non-scalar type QList<ListItem *> requested`

I know that the `selectedItems()` function returns a list of `QListWidgetItem`, is there a way to use this function with the `ListItem` class, which i derived from `QListWidgetItem`?

Comment: When you iterate over the list, just do an appropriate cast to the derived type (eg: `static_cast<ListItem*>(item)`). If you need an actual  list of derived-class pointers you will need to build a new one (iterate over the base-class list and add the items to your derived-class list)

Comment: `QList<ListItem *> results;` `for(QListWidgetItem *it: selectedItems()){ results << static_cast<ListItem *>(it);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is use `QList<QListWidgetItem *>` to get the result for `selectedItems()` and use `ListItem *myItem = static_cast<ListItem *>(item)` when you need to get the item from the list.

But, because the list is only of pointers, is safe do this:

```
QList<ListItem *> items = *reinterpret_cast<QList<ListItem *>*>(&selectedItems());
```